# How in the hoot do you successfully stream a remote mp3 file in swift 4?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, nsurl

I am working with swift 4 and cannot successfully stream an mp3 file to my device. There are no errors to lead me anywhere. What am I missing as far as AVPlayers capabilities? It seems others have had success streaming remote mp3 files. Additionally, the server is https.

```
let newUrl = NSURL(string: urlMain)
let test = AVPlayer(url: newUrl as! URL)
test.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable of AVPlayer insider your class.

```
let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

Then create AVPlayerItem and set to player.

```
func prepareToPlayAudio() {
    let url = newUrl
    asset = AVAsset(url: url)

    let assetKeys = ["playable", "hasProtectedContent"]

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset,
                              automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)

    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: &playerItemContext)

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

Then add observers to track the state of playing item.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard context == &playerItemContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItemStatus

        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItemStatus(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
        // Ready to play.
        case .failed:
        // Player item error.
        case .unknown:
            // Item is not ready.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent advice with the Observer! Giving this a shot now

Comment: After fixing the code to 4.2 standards I receive this error - Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'CGLayerGetContext' is a function

Comment: Specifically, I would like to stream this mp3 - https://novelnoise.com/Audio/Acoustic:Folk/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3

Comment: I am able to stream within the simulator but not on an actual device.

Comment: Make sure your actual device isn't on silent mode. It works on ringing mode.

Comment: I'm an idiot... I literally never would have checked that.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get speechrecognizer and an mp3 playing working at the saming time?

Comment: Not sure if it could recognise voice with headsets on, but device couldn't recognise voice when music is playing on speakers.